# How can I make precise, repeatable cuts in ABS plastic sheet?

Tags: cutting, plastic

I need to make a few fairly repeatable and accurate cuts out of a 12" x 12" x 1/8" piece of ABS plastic.

I've tried sawing, scoring with exacto knife followed by breaking off, and of course sanding. The issue with these methods is 1) it's time consuming, but more importantly 2) the pieces aren't 'similar enough', they don't repeat within, say 1/8" (more or less may be sanded, oftentimes not exactly straight, etc).

So one idea I had was to use something like this:

https://www.amazon.ca/X-ACTO-Commercial-12-Inch-Guillotine-26612/dp/B002JGMIA8/

I.e. one of those paper cutter tools. I don't mind if it takes a bit of elbow grease to get the cuts going, my main concern is that I'll get a long, straight-as-possible edge that I can repeat as consistently as possible about a dozen times.

Before I invest in something like this, what do you think, is this a good idea? Is there anything else you'd recommend for my problem? Thanks!

Comment: Agree with the other answer is to use a table saw with the proper blade.  If this is a one time need and just a few cut, check with TAP plastic or similar store and see if they will cut it for you.  It will be a perfect cut.

Comment: A paper cutter (of any reasonable size/weight/cost) won't do it.

A sheet metal shear might, but may also exceed "reasonable" size/weight/cost (or the plastic might shatter when cutting it - probably not with ABS, though.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution for this job would be to use a table saw. These are obviously not cheap, but you could probably find one that is not too expensive, especially if you have an 1/8" tolerance on your pieces. A used one can also be had reasonably, or you can rent or borrow one.

Answer (score 0):

I have one of those when the material gets two thick it shifts the cut as you get away from the pivot. I have used it to cut several thicknesses of contact paper very repeatedly for a stencil cutter but that is still much thinner and softer material. I really don’t think it would work.

Comment: Any better solutions you'd recommend?

Comment: As the other answer suggests a table saw might be your best bet as the material is rigid enough to score not knowing the how rigid the product is why I did not mention a saw , I have used a hot wire I built to cut plastics that were not stiff enough to push through a saw using nichrome wire but that is probably a little over the top for most diy folks , I have also used a Dremel with cut off disks it worked ok but was not fast enough that’s why I made the hot wire. I actually used the cutter I broke to build my hot wire.